# What is the meaning of "...drunk on sensations"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, collocations

> - we were almost ***drunk*** ***on*** ***sensations***.

I couldn't find any translation for this phrase **drunk** **on** **sensations**.

Comment: To become drunk on something means to become inebriated by it, whatever it is.  *We were drunk on laughter.* or *They were drunk on their power.*  It is used figuratively there to refer to judgment impaired by giddiness or some other mental aberration. Normally (literally) it is drunk on wine | beer | whisky, etc    **sensations** refers to feelings and perceptions.  It could refer to  hedonistic pleasures of some kind. Sex, drugs, rock-and-roll?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You should really start giving answers and not comments!

Comment: @Sovereign Sun:  I do give answers aplenty :)  If the question is really specific, I tend to comment rather than answer.

Comment: Please include the full context!

Answer (score 1):

"**drunk on sensations**" is used figuratively here and means "*experience (receive) too many sensations*"

"**drunk on**" means "drink too much alcohol":

- He was drunk on vodka. - He drank too much vodka.
- The girl is drunk on wine. - She drank too much wine.

Edit: I found this text [**here**](http://product.pearsonelt.com/newtotalenglish/samples/Intermediate/NTEIntUnit6-Sample.pdf)

> For six hours we shot through the barren landscape of the Karoo desert in South Africa. Just rocks and sand and baking sun. Knowing our journey was ending, Daniel and I just wanted to remember all we had seen and done. He used a camera. I used words. I had already finished three notebooks and was into the fourth, a beautiful leather notebook I’d bought in a market in Mozambique. Southern
>   Africa was full of stories. And visions. **We were almost drunk on sensations.** The roaring of the water at Victoria Falls, the impossible silence of the Okavango Delta in Botswana. And then the other things: dogs in the streets, whole families in Soweto living in one room, a kilometre from clean water.

Comment: It also has the meaning to become "*incapacitated* in one's judgement", in the same way one becomes *drunk* on alcohol. Odd there's no equivalent expression for "*beer goggles*" for desire of *things* other than the opposite sex.